# FormGroup async validator not called if FormControl is in error

Tags: validation, angular, asynchronous

I've wrote an async validator for a specific field an another one for 2 fields of the form:

```js
this.aliasCtrl = formBuilder.control('', [], [
  (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if(control.value === 'aaa') {
        resolve({error: true});
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  }
]);

this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
  firstName: formBuilder.control('', []),
  lastName: formBuilder.control('', []),
  alias: this.aliasCtrl
}, {
  asyncValidator: (group: FormGroup) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if(group.value.firstName === 'aaa' && group.value.lastName === 'aaa') {
        resolve({error2: true});
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Both of them are working correctly. The point is, when the alias control validator throws an error (when the field contains `aaa`), the "global" one never does.

A plunker of my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyr48ke7fWEUwrXy43tn?p=preview

**How to reproduce:**

1. put `aaa` in all fields starting with the first one. Good, everything works.
2. Reload the plunker.
3. put `aaa` in all fields starting with the last one. The "global" validator is not called when editing `firstName` of `lastName` field (I've added some `console.log` in the plunker to watch when validators are called).

Is the behaviour intentional? Why? How to call the "global" validator event if an error already exists?

Comment: if error already exists then you probably done with validation.

Comment: Then why the validator of `alias` field is triggered when I already have an error (with `firstName` and `lastName` equals to `aaa` if I fill them before `alias` field)? I think we need consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to answer my question is to define a `formGroup` containing fields `firstName` and `lastName`. Here's a plunker with the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/HAmaYySbxVE15VOl9uJ4?p=preview

For reference, I let here my `formGroup`:

```js
this.aliasCtrl = formBuilder.control('', [], [(control: AbstractControl) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if(control.value === 'aaa') {
        resolve({error: true});
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  }
]);

this.nameGroup = formBuilder.group({
  firstName: formBuilder.control('', []),
  lastName: formBuilder.control('', [])
}, {
  asyncValidator: (group: FormGroup) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      if(group.value.firstName === 'aaa' && group.value.lastName === 'aaa') {
        resolve({error2: true});
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  }
});

this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
  name: this.nameGroup,
  alias: this.aliasCtrl
});
```