# FormGroup asyncValidator is not being called?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I have been researching this issue for long time now, I found a couple of questions on SO, but none helped me fixing the issue. this is the closest problem to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817049/formgroup-async-validator-not-called-if-formcontrol-is-in-error). I am trying to call an asyncValidator for the formGroup but i can't get it to work. any help would be really appreciated,

in the code below, the http request is not even fired,

this is my `formGroup`,

```
 const partners = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    this.patientRestrationForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        patientFileId: new FormControl(null),
        firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        secondName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        aliasName: new FormControl(null),
        patientDob: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        patientEmail: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]),
        socialSecurityNo: new FormControl(null),
        passportNo: new FormControl(null),
        countryCodeId: new FormControl(null),
        patientMobileNo: new FormControl(null),
        partners: partners,
      },
      {
         asyncValidator: (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return this.asyncValidator.bind(control)
    }

      });
```

and this is `asyncValidator`

```
 asyncValidator(control: AbstractControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const patientFileId = control.get('patientFileId');
    const countryCodeId = control.get('countryCodeId');
    const patientMobileNo = control.get('patientMobileNo');
    const patientEmail = control.get('patientEmail');
    if (patientEmail.value) {
      return this.asyncValidationService.validateEmailNotTaken(patientEmail, patientFileId)
    }
  }
```

and my service,

```
public validateEmailNotTaken(a: AbstractControl, b?): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }>  {
    console.log('called::', a.value);
    return this.httpService.getRequest(
      'PatientsRegistration/IsPatientEmailExist' + '?control=' + a.value + '&id=' + b.value,
    ).map((response: HttpResponse<boolean>) => {
      return !response.body ? null : { asyncInvalid: true };
    });
  }
```

#### UPDATE,

```
 <form [formGroup]="patientRestrationForm" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="nope"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

A minimal prod is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9djs1)

Comment: Can you please add the part where you link the form to the template?

Comment: @Supamiu, I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator has to be linked to a field, your `asyncValidator` isn't linked to a field in your form, that's why it's never called (see [Angular - Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)).

Your async validation logic is relying on multiple field, I think you should set this logic on submit event so you can make sure all the properties are set (if you set them to required using `Validators.required`) and you'll be able to make your request to kno if the whole form is valid (as this validator doesn't link to a single field).

The solution is to remove this `asyncValidator` and to put its logic into your submit method, setting an error flag to true if the request doesn't validate form's content.

Sidenote: `return this.asyncValidator.bind(control)` can't work, binding to control will result in `this` being the control, where `asyncValidationService` is undefined. You shouldn't use bind here.

Comment: Thanks, but how the async fn is supposed to run,,,,, according to the docs, `formGroups` is just like `formControls`

`const form = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl('')
  passwordConfirm: new FormControl('')
}, {validators: passwordMatchValidator, asyncValidators: otherValidator});`

Comment: yes but as you can see, a formControl is bound to one input only, where your validator gets multiple values in the form, that's not how controls are meant to be used. Also, you're binding validators and asyncValidators in two different objects, which isn't the documented way of using validators.

Comment: I retested now, the async function run only if the whole form is valid

Comment: Yes, because the form wont submit if the inputs aren't valid, that's why your validation can't work like you expect it to.